# Multithreaded valgrind with flag --track-origins=yes

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, valgrind

I am currently trying to run my multi-thread program through valgrind, and when I execute the following command, I am notified of "Use of uninitialized values" and other related issues.

```
valgrind ./foo.exe
```

When I run it again, this time tracking origins, as follows, no errors pop up.

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./foo.exe
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am pretty sure the problem occurs only because my program uses multiple threads.

Comment: Sounds like a Heisen-Bug: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: I've resolved the issues that i was attempting to use valgrind for, but i'm still curios as to why valgrind 'bugs' out here

Comment: You could also run your program with the Sanitizers: `-fsanitize=thread` `-fsanitize=undefined` `-fsanitize=address`

Comment: sanitizers don't play nice with valgrind ... "use of uninitialized value" can only mean one thing, and comes with a function, file, and line number ...

Comment: did you try adding --trace-children=yes ?